# Using PostGIS geometry for ArcSDE database?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, enterprise-geodatabase

I just enabled my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with ArcSDE. Since I did this, when I copy and paste a dataset into my database via ArcCatalog, the dataset is not visible in QGIS.

This is because there is no geometry according to QGIS. I want to use ArcSDE database with all its benefits in ArcMap, but still be able to add this dataset in QGIS via a PostGIS connection.

How do I make sure that ArcGIS uploads the table with PostGIS geometry?

I almost have a solution by changing the ArcSDE table `sde_dbtune` to contain Default Geometry_Storage of PG_GEOMETRY, but if I upload a new dataset via ArcCatalog, the table is still not visible in QGIS.

It does work if I change the config.keyword to PG_GEOMETRY in Catalog (see image), but shouldnt it have to work on DEFAULTS too since I changed the settings?

[image]

I use PostgreSQL version 9.4, PostGIS 2.1.8 and ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Make the default DBTUNE geometry storage keyword "PG_GEOMETRY".

Comment: I changed the sde table sde_dbtune the Default Geometry_storage to PG_GEOMETRY, but I still cannot see a dataset in QGIS. Was this what you meant?

Comment: Sort of. The change only affects tables created *after* the change is made. Did you create any new tables?

Comment: Yes, I did. I just saw that I can change the config. keyword to PG_GEOMETRY if I do a data transfer in ArcCatalog and then it works, but if I leave this at default, I have the same problem. Also in Postgres I see that the shape column is still st_geometry for some reason. I reset the database in postgres and in catalog but without result

Comment: **Which** keyword did you change? Which keyword do you use? Please **edit the question** with details (including the PG and PostGIS versions, and the version of Desktop). Your "leave this as default" comment is unclear.

Comment: Apparantly, it works now. Maybe it took some time to make the changes. Thanks. There is however a new issue since it doesnt register tables in sde_geometry columns anymore. And therefore I cannot change the name of my dataset in arcCatalog. Shall I make a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, very different question.  You should be careful of using "dataset" when you mean "feature class" or "table", since an object exists named "feature dataset".

Comment: I will, thank you for the feedback concerning this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default geometry creation type for ArcGIS in PostgreSQL databases depends on the version of software and how it's installed.

On Amazon RDS instances, where it's not possible to add the sde.st_geometry type, the geodatabase enablement code is able to detect RDS is in use, and the default DBTUNE entry is automatically altered to:

```
       keyword: "DEFAULTS"
parameter_name: "GEOMETRY_STORAGE"
 config_string: "PG_GEOMETRY"
```

On other PostgreSQL enterprise geodatabase-enabled databases, the default on initial install is:

```
       keyword: "DEFAULTS"
parameter_name: "GEOMETRY_STORAGE"
 config_string: "ST_GEOMETRY"
```

ArcGIS 10.4 and higher can write to PostgreSQL 9.3 and higher *without* enabling an enterprise geodatabase, and therefore use PostGIS `geometry` as a default.

The `sdedbtune` command-line utility was used to edit DBTUNE keywords at ArcGIS 10.2 and earlier, but that tool was deprecated, and a pair of ArcPy toolbox tools were added at 10.3:

- [arcpy.ExportGeodatabaseConfigurationKeywords_management()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/export-geodatabase-configuration-keywords.htm)
- [arcpy.ImportGeodatabaseConfigurationKeywords_management()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/import-geodatabase-configuration-keywords.htm)

I've generally just used SQL to make a simple change to one keyword parameter (but you need to make sure the transaction has committed before you try using it).

Note that the environment you have listed -- ArcGIS 10.2.x with PG 9.4.x and PostGIS 2.1.x -- is not a supported configuration.  PostgreSQL 9.4 support was added [at ArcGIS 10.4](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.4/database-requirements-postgresql.htm) (though it would probably work at ArcGIS 10.3.x).  Always search on "system requirements" from desktop.arcgis.com to research RDBMS compatibility before enabling a geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I know about the configuration, my company will update to 10.4 in January, but we wanted to prepare the database already

Comment: arcpy import gets parameters named "input_databse" and "in_file". But file conents are not defiled enywhere. How can I find file contents?

Comment: @barteloma Please ask new questions in a new Question.

Comment: can add give an SQL example of changing a single keyword?

Comment: Can you please clarify how to do this? "ArcGIS 10.4 and higher can write to PostgreSQL 9.3 and higher without enabling an enterprise geodatabase, and therefore use PostGIS geometry as a default." I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 with PostGRES 10.3/Post GIS 2.4. I need to be able to edit polygon features regardless of client (QGIS/ArcGIS desktop). If I create a POSTGIS database and tables in pgAdmin 4, I would like to be able to add and edit that data with either client.

Comment: @user1547290 This is a very different question, which should be asked standalone. Note that ArcGIS does not support geodatabase editing on a non-geodatabase RDBMS instance,

Comment: @mattwilkie I've been asked to refrain from providing explicit unsupported solutions, especially ones that can corrupt the data creation metadata of an instance. If the `UPDATE` SQL is obvious, you're not likely to leave off the appropriate `WHERE` (and if you do, you'll have a better chance of recovering without a call to my colleagues in Tech Support)

Comment: Thanks for sharing and following up, albeit within the limits you've been asked to abide by