# create spatial view in postgis on an ArcGIS table with ST_Geometry type

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, st-geometry, postgis-2.2

I am working on PostgreSQL 9.4.5 with Postgis 2.2.3.

I work on a spatial table created on ArcGIS, with geometry type "ST_POINT". I would like to create a spatial view of that table in postgreSQL using aggregation on few columns. However, I can't figure out how to write the query on how to aggregate my ST_POINT geometries into a multipoint geometry (ST_MultiPoint) in my spatial view.

Below is the script I am running, without success. The non-spatial aggregation is working perfectly fine for what I need (I tested it removing the geometry column) but I keep running into errors on whatever I try to write for aggregating the points into multipoint.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW global_ops AS 
 SELECT string_agg(a.country, ', ') as country,
 a.rb,
 a.start_date,
 a.end_date,
 a.op_type,
 string_agg(a.activity, ', ') as activities,
 SUM(a.planned) as total_planned,
 a.links,
 a.year,
 a.project_num,
 SUM(a.actual_transfers) as total_actual,
 string_agg(a.transfer_modality, ', ') as modalities,
 sde.st_multipoint(st_AsText(''||a.shape||'')) as shape
 FROM global_ops_2018 a GROUP BY a.rb, a.start_date, 
 a.end_date, a.op_type, a.links, a.year, a.project_num, a.shape ORDER BY 
 a.project_num ASC;
```

This line here

```
sde.st_multipoint(st_AsText(''||a.shape||'')) as shape
```

is the one I'm trying to solve. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using PG_Geometry if you have PostGIS installed? ArcGIS doesn't make much difference either way. ST_Geometry is the Esri proprietary format which may not like being manipulated in this way.

Comment: which geometry backend are you trying to use? PG_Geomery or ST_Geometry?

Comment: The geometry of my table is ST_Geometry as the geodatabase I'm working on is setup with this geometry type. However, I could move it to another geodatabase that has PG_Geometry quite easily

Comment: okay, then why are you putting the a.shape through the st_astext function before it goes through the multipoint function?

Comment: @ziggy it probably shows how desperate I was? Please just disregard this one. The ST_AsText was mainly to try to solve the issue of converting from ST_Geometry to PG_Geometry, even though the query is very incomplete. I might try to create a PG_Geometry version of my table as suggested by Michael Stimson

Comment: check out this question I asked, it might help you. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252533/postgis-and-arcsde-mixed-environment

Comment: I would caution against advice to always use PG Geometry.  Whether you use PG geometry or ST_Geometry is going to come down to how you are using your data.  The size of your data.  And if you are using ArcGIS Server, the version and which set of bugs come with that version.  I've issued multiple cases through Esri Support--an outcome of one case was to use PostGIS geometry.  The outcome of the other was to use Esri's ST_Geometry!  I certainly prefer PostGIS geometry, but you have to be careful when Esri is in your stack.

Comment: You have a point @JayCummins, that's a decision to be made with some weight. PG_Geometry allows for more latitude with supported interfaces but comes with its own set of nuances and bugs. I'm not an expert in PostgreSQL, I comment more from curiosity about this subject than from a SQL viewpoint.. I do have experience in manipulating geometries from SDE and know that Esri objects often require an Esri license to be manipulated; it may be different if you're working directly with the database but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I maintain one system that uses both Esri ST_Geometry and PG Geometry and I can insert into tables with either data type (just can't mix them).  For convenience, I have a few conversion functions between the two (e.g. `geom := ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(l_st_geometry),3857);` if I need to cross over.  And there's a couple of  large tables that I have that use st_geometry and I maintain a side table of the pg geometry via triggers--that way ArcGIS Server performs fast, but I can still issue postgis queries and join over to the st_geometry table.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think I'll rather convert my table to PG_Geometry as it will be easier to manipulate it on PostgreSQL. We use PG_Geometry for many other datasets in my organisation (using also ArcGIS server for example) and don't have any issues or bugs, at least for the use we are making. But I can't tell for more complex ArcGIS database management functionalities such as versioning etc, as I've never used it with a table with PG_Geometry.

Comment: at lot my issues were with 10.2.x.  We are now at 10.5.1, but left everything in place because it works (don't fix what isn't broken).    I have another system that is 10.4.x with all PostGIS geometry and I don't have the really bad queries coming from ArcGIS (like `SELECT *` with no predicate on tables with millions of rows for an extent that should only return 4 features).  But I have not used it with versioning or other complex geodatabase data structures.

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestions in the comments above, I have decided to convert my spatial table created with ArcGIS from ST_Geometry to PG_Geometry. After doing that, I was able to simply use a ST_Collect(a.shape) function for aggregating my points into a multipoint spatial view.

Thanks!