# Create ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase - postgres ST_GEOMETRY.so error

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql-9.5

I am creating, or attempting to create, an enterprise geodatabase using PostgreSQL 9.5 (via the postgres:9.5-alpine Docker image) and arcpy on ArcGIS Server 10.5.1, both on Linux. I have followed [the instructions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/setup-geodatabase-postgresql-linux.htm) for setting the database up, such that:

1. st_geometry.so for Linux64 9.5 is copied to `/usr/local/lib/postgresql/`, and is readable by the postgres user
2. LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PGDATA, and PATH are all set to the correct values
3. The PostgreSQL role (postgres) has superuser privileges

However, when I run

```
arcpy.CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase_management('PostgreSQL', host_name, 
     db_name, True, 'postgres', db_pw, 'SDE_SCHEMA', 'sde', sde_pw, 
     authorization_file='/home/arcgis/authorization.ecp')
```

I still get this error:

*arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: You must copy the latest ST_GEOMETRY library to the PostgreSQL software location. Refer to the ArcGIS help topics for more details.*

*Connected RDBMS instance is not setup for Esri spatial type configuration.*

Is there something I'm missing, or a way to more precisely diagnose  what (else) might be causing this error?

Comment: Not sure of my suggestion, but just in case : shouldn't you activate a postgis extension in pgAdmin ? (CREATE EXTENSION postgis;) ...hum..maybe not, it activates the PG_GEOMETRY i think. Not your problem it seems.

Comment: ArcGIS enterprise geodatabases use a different geometry implementation than PostGIS, which is why the st_geometry.so is necessary. But, thanks for replying!

Comment: Actually, I suggested that because you can use the PG_GEOMETRY is necessary ;) My data is hosted in an enterprise GDB using PG_GEOMETRY (see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/configuration-keywords-for-enterprise-geodatabases.htm). You just need to use the right keyword when you save into your e-gdb. But i'm not sure it solves your installation problem.

Comment: So why did the other documentation I read say that wasn't supported?!? Sigh, ESRI . 

Comment: have a try here maybe ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252533/postgis-and-arcsde-mixed-environment seems it starts with arcgis 10.4