# QGIS NoGeometry

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I can't edit features in QGIS 3.8.3 on Mac (OS is not a problem, the same happens on Windows 10) because spatial type of layers is NoGeometry
When add layers, they seem to be simple tables without geometry

Everything works fine in ArcGIS ArcMap 10.5, 10.7.1, I can edit.
[image: Data Source Manager]

I am using docker container with PostgreSQL 11.7 and PostGIS 2.5.3
[image: Docker container settings]

P.S. Don't try to use QGIS higher than 3.8, you will not even open tables inside schemas.

Comment: Is the geometry stored as a PostGIS geometry type? Or are you using ArcGIS Server?

Comment: It looks like this the back-end of an ArcGIS system?

Comment: ArcGIS creates and can work with two geometry data types in PostgreSQL: Esri ST_Geometry or PostGIS Geometry, I think QGIS use only PostGIS Geometry while you probably have Esri ST_Geometry so QGIS doesn't recognize the geometry....

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto, the layers were created and stored in arcmap. Obviously necessary st_geometry.so and other file were added to lib directory to postgres catalog/folder

Comment: QGIS can't use the layers because they are not in the PostGIS geometry type. Rather they are in the proprietary Esri ST_Geometry type. You would have the change the configuration of the database to store the data as PostGIS native geometry. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252533/postgis-and-arcsde-mixed-environment